# Does the TV show "Maison Close" use standard French or period French?

Tags: histoire, télévision

I'm using it to learn and I was wondering if anyone knew whether it uses dated French as it takes place in the 1800s I think… like how in Jane Austen English films the characters speak a bit differently since they used to speak more "formally" in those days.  Any tips?

Edit:  I found an episode on Youtube. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9HZa4aXjY4

So, can I speak like this now or is the way they are speaking dated?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't watched the TV show, but from the "[bande annonce](http://www.canalplus.fr/c-series/c-maison-close/pid5290-videos.html)", the language seems to be modern. As you observed, the formulations are a tad different, adapted to sound like 1800s.

From the episode, I can clearly affirm that vocabulary is modern French. The sentence formulation could be used as it is in everyday life, but some time it would look "snooty".

p.s.: You should keep in mind that this language would look a little bit weird in Quebec.

Comment: No, I haven't observed any formulations ...I was talkng about the my English comparisons.  So, tbe French they are using is dated?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Why would it look snooty?  So, it's too formal French?  Like the French in Maison Close is more formal than regular TV shows or French films?  Weird in Quebec because of the vocabulary?

Comment: The language is too neat and may sound like a roman. Writing like that is perfect, but when speaking with people, it might seems that you are trying to show your superiority. It is just a question of perception, however.

Comment: A roman? So, in fact this show does use different French compared to popular French TV shows in France?

Comment: So, it would just be weird in Quebec?

Comment: It seems to me it is a tad different, but I do not often watch French TV. Again, it is really a matter of perception. You would be perfectly understood speaking like them, but no I would not speak like that in my everyday life (I confirm it would sound weird in Quebec, but maybe it is also the case in France)

Comment: Do you mind giving me an English comparison as to HOW different/formal is the language compared to everyday talking?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good modern french language, not familiar. Except if i don't speak my natif language correctly....

Comment: C'est quand même plus théâtral que dans la vraie vie.

Comment: Lol ^^ Ben oui. Mais d'un côté t'imagines s'ils disaient dans un film ayant pour sujet le début du 20ème siècle une phrase du genre "ouaich mec, t'as pas une clope ?"

Comment: Can anyone translate these comments? :-)